# Identify spatial neighbors and account for NAs in R (sp, rgeos)

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I am trying to identify the neighborhing spatial polygon to a set of spatial polygons, while accounting for whether a neighbor exists or is NA. I'm using the `gTouches()` function from the `rgeos` package to identify which geometries share a common border, however I don't know how to make it account for whether the value of the neighbor is an NA, in which case I would like it to find the next closest geometry. In the following example code, I would like the neighbors for `tr2`, which includes an NA, to be different than `tr`:

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

grid <- GridTopology(c(0,0), cellsize = c(1,1), cells.dim = c(5,5)) 
poly <- as(grid, "SpatialPolygons")         
id <- names(poly)   

tr <- 13                            ### Define this as the grid for which to find neighbors         
g.id <- sprintf("g%i", tr)              ###     
tr <- ifelse(id %in% g.id, 1, 0)    
tr2 <- ifelse(id %in% g.id, 1, 0)   
tr2[8] <- NA

ex <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly, data = data.frame(id = id, tr = tr, tr2 = tr2, row.names = row.names(poly)))   
adj <- gTouches(poly, poly[which(ex$tr==1)], byid = TRUE)
nbrs <- as.vector(apply(adj,1,which))

adj2 <- gTouches(poly, poly[which(ex$tr2==1)], byid = TRUE)
nbrs2 <- as.vector(apply(adj2,1,which))

nbrs            
  [1]  7  8  9 12 14 17 18 19
nbrs2   ### Should be 2,3,4 (replace 8), 7, 9, 12, 14, 17, 18, 19
  [1]  7  8  9 12 14 17 18 19
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Following this logic, I assume you want `2 3 4` to replace `8`, not just `3`?

Comment: Yes, that's right; editing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an NA in `nbrs2`, you could join the initial polygon with whichever has an `NA` in `tr2` and use `gTouches` on the joined polygon:

```
library(maptools)
if(any(is.na(tr2[nbrs2]))) {
        to_join <- nbrs2[which(is.na(tr2[nbrs2]))]
        joined_polygon <- unionSpatialPolygons(poly[c(which(tr2==1),to_join)],rep(1,length(to_join)+1))
        adj2 <- gTouches(poly,joined_polygon,byid=TRUE)
        nbrs2 <- as.vector(apply(adj2,1,which))
}
nbrs2


#[1]  2  3  4  7  9 12 14 17 18 19
```

`to_join` find the number of the polygon that is next to 13 and has an `NA` in tr2. Then we can use `unionSpatialPolygons` from `maptools` to join polygon 13 and polygon 8, then use `gTouches` as you did in your code to find all the adjacent polygons.